# Is it possible to turn off Mac OS X extension hiding?

Tags: macos, finder

On the Mac, a lot of programs hide the .zzz extension by default. Is there a way to turn this behaviour off so that extensions are never hidden by default?

I know I don't actually need it, I just prefer it to be there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With Finder active, hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to go to preferences.  In the advanced section, you will find the option to show file extensions.

Comment: great! it works

Answer (score 2):

`AppleShowAllExtensions` controls this behavior. It defaults to `0` (`false`). Read the value by entering this in a terminal:

```sh
defaults read -g AppleShowAllExtensions
```

Set it to `1` (`true`) by entering the following in a terminal:

```sh
defaults write -g AppleShowAllExtensions -bool TRUE
```

To also restart the Finder so that the change takes effect immediately (rather than after restarting / logging out & back in):

```sh
defaults write -g AppleShowAllExtensions -bool TRUE && killall Finder
```

To reset to the default value (and restart the Finder):

```sh
defaults delete -g AppleShowAllExtensions && killall Finder
```

Resources:

- https://macos-defaults.com/finder/appleshowallextensions.html
- `defaults` documentation is available at https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/defaults.1.html and https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html.
- Some basic instructions on using the macOS Terminal app can be found on [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/open-or-quit-terminal-apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/mac).
- Duplicate Q&A on a different Stack Exchange site: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423337/what-is-the-terminal-command-for-show-all-filename-extensions