# Is it possible to turn off Mac OS X extension hiding for a specific extension type?

Tags: macos, finder, preview.app

My question is similar to [Is it possible to turn off Mac OS X extension hiding?](https://superuser.com/questions/35364/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-mac-os-x-extension-hiding), however, I'd like to disable extension hiding for one specific extension type: `.pdf` The Preview app hides the extension by default when exporting to PDF and there seems to be no setting to disable this behavior.

Is it possible to somehow disable extension hiding for a specific extension type on OSX?

Comment: Unlikely, unless you can find some 3rd party tool that might be able to do it. The pref is a global. Even if you could refine that further to a single app, that app would be Finder, so it would still be all or nothing within Finder itself.